# What is the best way of assigning a variable from an object value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variable-assignment, destructuring

I want to know what the better option is when getting values out of an object:

```
const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = React.useState(getCurrentMonth(language).label)
```

or:

```
const { label: labelMon } = getCurrentMonth(language)
const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = React.useState(labelMon)
```

I want to use the value only once to set the initial state.

Comment: You can do something like this:

`const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(getCurrentMonth(language))`

Comment: As long as you know the value is readily available (before dom is ready), you can use option 1 for a one-liner, and option 2 if you want cleaner codes. (no performance differences). The answers below using useEffect are only useful if `getCurrentMonth` is available **only** after page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this once it happens

```
 useEffect(() => {
const { label: labelMon } = getCurrentMonth(language)
   setCurrentMonth(labelMon )
  },[]);
```